# Integrate Flask with Faust

Tags: flask, python-3.6, gevent, eventlet, faust

I'm trying to get a faust agent to cast a message inside a flask view/endpoint,
I can't find any example of it and i'm really struggling.

Has anyone tried this successfully?
the docs say to use gevent or eventlet as a bridge to asyncio but can't understand how unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `monkeypatch` your flask application with gevent or eventlet. As far as I know eventlet is the only one which is currently working since the bridge [aiogevent](https://pypi.org/project/aiogevent/) is no longer available in pip.

Another approach is to delegate your Flask app to only produce messages with [pykafka](https://pykafka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python). In this way you will keep both applications isolated, flask producing and faust consuming. Note that by default faust will try to create topics without `internal` flag with 1 replica and internal topics with 8 replicas.

Comment: thanks, in the end i went for the solution #2 with kafka-python and seems to be working fairly well for our use case.

would still be nice to see the implementation of #1 as i literally have no clue

Comment: @shipperizer Can you please help me here with the solution with the first approach if not 2nd also works for me.
Looking for the solution since ages and I am stuck right now.

Comment: @sahil-paudel simply add a kafka producer to the flask blueprint at startup/bootstrap, then call it from.tour endpoint via app.kafka and use the send method. It s completely separated from Faust, we made it sharing the same marshmallow object so stuff sent to kafka is the same

Comment: Can you show me a sample code if you don't mind.
Did you use faust at all? I am little uncomfortable using faust

Answer (score 0):

The faust docs have a suggestion for integrating flask and faust. It involves using `gevent`, but I do not believe it requires monkeypatching.

From the docs (https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html):

```
This approach works with any blocking Python library that can work with gevent.

Using gevent requires you to install the aiogevent module, and you can install this as a bundle with Faust:

$ pip install -U faust[gevent]
Then to actually use gevent as the event loop you have to either use the -L option to the faust program:

$ faust -L gevent -A myproj worker -l info
or add import mode.loop.gevent at the top of your entry point script:

#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mode.loop.gevent
REMEMBER: It’s very important that this is at the very top of the module, and that it executes before you import libraries.
```